# how to integrate "at" command in python

Tags: python

I need to integrate  " echo /bin/meteo | at 23:00 today " in to a python script.

In the python script the command "at 23:00 today" should call the bash script /bin/meteo

I did install plumbum and intergrated this in my python scrip.

```
from plumbum.cmd import echo, grep
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how to proceed from here.

I tryed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

    if pfd.input_pins[0].value ==0:
        cmd = "echo /bin/meteo | at 06:36 today"
        subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

but the lights in /bin/meteo are randomly swiching on and off (not blinking as they should)

They do it from 06:36 until 06:37 and not only 5 times.

/bin/meteo:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

for i in {1..5}; do   #blink 5x
echo -n -e "\x37\x00\x55" | nc -u -q 1 192.168.0.6 8899 #Zone 3 on
sleep 0.1
echo -n -e "\x3A\x00\x55" | nc -u -q 1 192.168.0.6 8899 #Zone 3 off
done
sleep 0.1
exit
```

Comment: `subprocess.popen` will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) will run the command:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "echo /bin/meteo | at 23:00 today "
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

*Execute a child program in a new process. On Unix, the class uses os.execvp()-like behavior to execute the child program. On Windows, the class uses the Windows CreateProcess() function. The arguments to Popen are as follows*.

*args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.*

It is not totally clear what you want but you can run any commands like:

```
In [9]: cmd = "date"

In [10]: subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
Sun Jul  6 22:30:47 IST 2014
```

Or using sudo:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "sudo which python"
my_pass="xxxx"
subprocess.call('echo {} | sudo -S {}'.format(my_pass,cmd), shell=True)
In [29]: subprocess.call('echo {} | sudo -S {}'.format(my_pass,cmd), shell=True)
/usr/local/bin/python
Out[29]: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.4, it's easy to call a command and exchange input/output in a bulk:

```
subprocess.check_output(["at", "23:00", "today"], input="/bin/meteo")
```

Therefore in this very case, `shell=True` shouldn't be needed as we just call the `at` command with arguments and give it the script on input.

With older versions of python, this needs to be rewritten as:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["at", "23:00", "today"])
process.communicate(input="/bin/meteo")
```

With the `plumbum` module, you could instead use:

```
from plumbum.cmd import at, echo
(echo["/bin/meteo"] | at["23:30", "today"])()
```

But I don't believe that it's very useful.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: It depends on the way you use it. When you don't need to affect stdin/stdout as in the `shell=True` case, there's no reason to use `subprocess.Popen`. When you're using Python 3.4, `subprocess.check_output` is good enough. Only when you want to supply your own input and you're using an older version of Python, you have to use it.

Comment: so it is necessary for python 2?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: In this case, you need the Popen with Python 2 *but* you also need to use it correctly.